# php json_encode with variable for javascript

Tags: javascript, php

For example I want a JSON like this:

```
{"start": "2015-01-01", "end": "2015-01-01", "backgroundColor": Theme.colors.red}
```

how to pas `Theme.colors.red` as constant/variable instead of string to be process in javascript?

my php script currently look like:

```
$event = new StdClass;
$event->title = $off->note;
$event->start = date('D M d Y', strtotime($off->y.'-'.$off->m.'-'.$off->d));
$event->end = date('D M d Y', strtotime($off->y.'-'.$off->m.'-'.$off->d));
$event->backgroundColor = 'Theme.colors.red';
```

Comment: you can't really, no matter what you do with that you will have to parse it in the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a data exchange format. As such, it doesn't know what `Theme.colors.red` is.

In order to achieve your goal, in Javascript the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function can take a second parameter that works as a transforming function. For example:

```
var data = JSON.parse(rawJSON, function(key, value) {
    // Warning: eval is evil
    if (key === "backgroundColor") return eval(value);

    return value;
});
```

I don't know what `Theme.colors.red` is too, its scope and so on, so it's up to you to implement a transformer callback that fits your needs and avoids dangerous pitfalls.